# How do I fix a vinyl covering that is coming away from the outside deck support beam?

Tags: repair, deck

I live in a townhouse with a deck over the garage. I noticed that under the deck, along the board that is on the outer edge, some of the vinyl covering is popping out of place and hanging down a little. You can see two images of what I'm talking about here:

[image]
[image]

It appears that this rubbery cover is attached only at certain intervals, which is why you can see it popping out of place only in certain spots. If I push it back into place it looks fine, but it does not stay there when I let go. My assumption is that I can simply put some adhesive inside of the cover in the pieces that are limping and then duck tape the material into place while it dries.

Is that the proper way to fix something like this? And what type of adhesive would I use if I used one?

Comment: Vinyl needs to be able to expand and contract.  When we install siding, the screws always leave a fingernail gap underneath, and the ends are always cut a little short and concealed in the side channels.  I've never installed your product, but my assumption is that it hasn't been allowed to freely move, causing your issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an adhesive, [one of the liquid nails products](http://www.liquidnails.com/index.jsp) should work.  The comment about vinyl expanding and contracting is right, although it may not be a concern since it's under an overhang.  Vinyl siding gets really hot since it's on the side of your house exposed to the sun.